# Findbugs: RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED_BAD_PRACTICE using ExecutorService

Tags: java, executorservice, findbugs

I'm using Findbugs and I'm getting the RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED_BAD_PRACTICE next error, this is my code:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
      try {
        executor.submit(() -> {
          LOGGER.info(
              ".............",
              Some Code.....
        });
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.info(".........);
      }
      finally {
        if (!executor.isTerminated()) {
          LOGGER.info(.....);
        }
        executor.shutdownNow();
        LOGGER.info(.........);
      }
```

The issue is in the line: `executor.submit(() -> {`

Any ideas?

Comment: It's telling you you're ignoring the return value (`RV`). Check the return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really don't care about the result of the execution, you should use `executor.execute(()-> {LOGGER.info(...)});` instead.